# How to get the active status of nested Angular UI Bootstrap tabs

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my code I'm using a service (ngResource) to get data dynamically from the server API to create a series of nested tabs.

My code is loosely like this:

```
var AdminMenu = angular.module('AdminMenu',  ['ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngGrid']);

AdminMenu.factory('myServices', ['$resource', function($resource) {

    return $resource('/api/categories?sort=createdAt asc');

}
```

and my controller

```
$scope.categories = myServices.categories.query();
```

On my template (jade) I have

```
tabset
                        if(categories)
                            tab(ng-repeat="category in categories", heading="{{category.name}}", active="category.active", disabled="category.disabled")

                                tabset

                                    tab(ng-model="subCats", ng-repeat="subcat in subCats", heading="{{subcat.name}}", active="tab.active") {{subcat.content}}
```

And that works ok, however I need to get the status (active and heading) of the second and third(not created yet) generation tabs. I can get it from the first generation as Angular seems to automatically add bits to each object of the first generation like `active:true`, some methods, etc. The same doesn't seem to apply to the subsequent generations.

Interestingly, the tabs are not declared in my controller (like `$scope.tabs = obj` for instance), they are being added dynamically.

How can I access the status and heading (all details, really) of each subsequent generation of tabs?

I've tried assign the second and third generation in my controller like so: `$scope.tabs2 = $scope.categories.subcategories` but that didn't work. I suspect it was because the data is being collected dynamically, but I'm not sure. Since I can't assign the tabs in my controller, I can't simply console `$scope.tabs2.active` to find out which tab is active.

Any suggestions?